# Flash - How to build exclusively for ipad?

Tags: ios, flash, ipad, air, flash-builder

I´ve built an app for the iOs in flash.
I successfully generated de .ipa package but on itunes connect the app shows for iphone and Ipad but i wanted distribute it exclusively on ipad.
I think it has something to do with the flash builder options but I can´t seem to find that option on flash builder or on the internet to build exclusively for ipad.

Does anyone know to build exclusively for the ipad in flash builder?

Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know how to do it in FB (click some chech box or whatever). But you can add something like the following in you `application.xml` file

```
<iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions>
        <![CDATA[
            <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
            <array>
                <string>2</string>
            </array>
        ]]>
    </InfoAdditions>
</iPhone>
```

Don't mind that node is called `iPhone`! `<string>2</string>` is essebtial here: 2 means that your app is for iPad only. All this stuff is described [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS789ea67d3e73a8b2-48bca492124b39ac5e2-7ffb.html).